# Robot SDK 0.9 is not complete. Please download it again or re-create the robot application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pepper

I followed the steps mentioned in https://android.aldebaran.com/doc/installation.html#installation to start developing appications for SoftBank's Pepper robot.

I installed android studio v2.3, pepper SDK plugin v0.9.0, Robot SDK platform v0.9 exactly following the tutorial. But I am unable to get it to work.
When launching the robot emulator it gives me error

> Robot SDK 0.9 is not complete. Please download it again or re-create
>   the robot application.

Has anyone here worked with pepper SDK before or know why is this happening?

Comment: This does not seem to be Robot Framework related, the test automation tool by the same name. Can you have a look at the used keywords?

Comment: corrected :) got confused

Comment: Hi @cain I have the same problem. Did you found a solution yet?

Comment: See my solution on this other question, hopefully it will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45002794/2833041

Comment: Do you still have the issue?