# Aldebaran's Pepper sdk for android/Robot sdk 0.9 "Robot SDK'0.9' is not complete. Please download it again or re-create the robot application."

Tags: android-studio-2.2, android-studio-2.1, android-studio-2.3, pepper

When trying to install the android sdk for Aldebaran's pepper robot on my computer following this official tutorial:

Step 1: android.aldebaran.com/doc/installation.html

Step 2: android.aldebaran.com/doc/create_project.html#create-project

When trying to launch the Virtual Robot Environment of Pepper's tablet on my computer this message is printed: "Robot SDK'0.9' is not complete. Please download it again or re-create the robot application."

So far I have tried the following on my Ubuntu 16.04 64bit computer:

- Uninstalling and re-downloading/installing the Robot sdk over the robot sdk manager provided by the android sdk for Pepper
- Uninstalling and re-downloading/installing the android sdk for Pepper
- Deleting, recreating and creating the android studio application turning it into a robot application
- Removing other non essential android sdks

Moreover I also tried the following on another computer running windows 8.1 64bit:

- Repeating the tutorial installation
- Downloading and installing older version such as 2.22 and 2.11 of the android studio and repeating the tutorial installation.

Each time after I have completed Steps 1 & 2 when I want to start building or launching the application it fails on step B from this tutorial: android.aldebaran.com/doc/run_debug.html#run-debug and prints the Error mentioned above.

The project structure is identical to the one in the tutorial and I am able to sync the project via maven. But as I cannot actually launch the virtual robot environment or run the application I cannot make use of this sdk.

I have also found a similar question being asked on stackoverflow but there hasn't been a response yet. Also I don't understand the comments.

stackoverflow.com/questions/42824942/robot-sdk-0-9-is-not-complete-please-download-it-again-or-re-create-the-robot-a

I tried using another computer with windows 10 64bit freshly formatted so I installed Java jdk & jre 1.8.0_121 and android studio 2.3.1 as I couldn't find 2.3.3:

- Repeated the tutorial installation

But still the same error message.

Answer (score 2):

I got mine to work doing the following:

- go to your current android SDK folder
- rename the tools folder to tools-old
- create a new Folder named tools
- download this: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/android-emulator/+archive/android-7.1.1_r1/windows.tar.gz
- unpacke it into your new tools folder

Make sure you have your AVD Options set to arm and not x86
and that "Use Host GPU" is enabled

After that the emulator worked.(note that it takes quite long to launche)

The suspected cause is that the Pepper emulator tries to use the emulator-arm.exe  wich is not availible in the standart installation of Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

You should try installing Android Studio 2.3.3 on Windows 10, 64-bit. I know that works at least.

Comment: I have some errors in this xml<Yourapplicationname>/app/src/main/assets/robot/robotsdk.xml
It says that the namespaces for neither android nor robot are bound. If I try to create a namespace declaration. I get this error URI is not registered(Settings|Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs)
But the "Robot SDK'0.9' is not complete. Please download it again or re-create the robot application." still persists

Comment: But the gradle build finishes and I don't even know if this is the core of my issues =P

Comment: Also I only found android 2.3.1 for download. Maybe that's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working finally thanks to theGary's hint above.  No need to wipe out your whole tools directory though -- I was able to get the x86 Pepper emulator running (on Mac in my case) by copying these files and directories from the Android sdk/emulator directory into the sdk/tools directory:

- emulator64-x84
- qemu
- bin64
- lib/pc-bios
- lib/ca-bundle.pem

Then edit your run/debug configurations and change the “robot app” AVD options from armeabi-v7 to x86.