# Robot SDK 0.9 is not complete

Tags: android-studio-2.1, pepper

I have installed Pepper SDK with Android Studio 2.1.2 but when I launch emulator, it gives error Robot SDK 0.9 is not complete. My Java version is 8 update 131. I have followed the steps perfectly as mentioned in the link https://android.aldebaran.com/doc/installation.html but still it does not work.

There is one more thread on Stack Overflow with the same question (link: [Robot SDK 0.9 is not complete. Please download it again or re-create the robot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42824942/robot-sdk-0-9-is-not-complete-please-download-it-again-or-re-create-the-robot-a)) but nobody has answered it yet.

Comment: In Q4 2017 a new release is planned for the Android SDK. I would not expect the current version to be fixed.

Comment: I just posted my solution on that other thread you referenced, maybe it will help you.